# Where are the raw data sources for all these maps?

Tags: data, api, twitter

Pretty straightforward question here.

At an increasing rate I see crowd sourcing data being mapped to great effect.  **Where are the raw data sources for all these maps?**  I know they vary but I don't think I have even found a single source.

For instance, twitter maps, where is the data?

Comment: Could you post a link to one of the maps you're seeing?

Comment: http://www.theatlanticwire.com/global/2011/11/worlds-languages-according-twitter/44690/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some places like Twitter connect geographical data with the content ("tweets" in this case).  If you use the API to request a list of recent tweets, it will give you geographical data along with it ("coordinates", "geo" in the JSON response):

[Twitter API Example](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline)

I suspect most of the data you're referring to is collected similarly.  Basically,

1. find a potential source of data with geographic information attached to it,
2. find out how to query their API, and
3. compile the data into a format your GIS tools can understand.

Comment: If you're interested in Twitter, this is how I did it: http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/tweets-to-qgis/